# How to hide row in chartJS when filtering?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

When I apply the filter and remove the category from the graph, 
 I need to be able to rebuild the graph and hide it from the y axis along with the space it occupies.
[image]

Perhaps there is some kind of callback that allows you to track the click on the axis and see if there is no data there and hide it

Comment: You can write your own custom legend onClick handler to achieve this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/legend.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that can be used to perform custom code.

1. The `labels` and `data` need to be defined outside the chart configuration.
2. In the `beforeUpdate` hook, you set the initial `labels` and `data` to the chart configuration.
3. In the `beforeElementsUpdate` hook you remove individual `labels` and corresponding `data` values from the chart configuration if all values for a certain label are `null` or if the `dataset` is `hidden`.

Please take a look at below runnable sample and see how it works.

```js
const labels = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
const data = [
  [10, null, 4],
  [9, null, 8],
  [3, 5, 8]
];

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    beforeUpdate: chart => {
      chart.data.labels = labels;
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => ds.data = data[i]);
    },
    beforeElementsUpdate: chart => {         
      let sums = labels.map((l, i) => chart.data.datasets.reduce((prev, ds, iDs) => prev + (chart.getDatasetMeta(iDs).hidden ? 0 : ds.data[i]), 0));
      chart.data.labels = labels.filter((l, i) => sums[i]);
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, iDs) => ds.data = data[iDs].filter((v, i) => sums[i]));
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 3',
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```